# Order 5 People of team A, 5 People of team B and 5 People of team C in line

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to calculate the probability that: **each candidate stands next to at least one candidate from their group.**

At first I thought that subtract from $1$ the probability that each team stands together,or subtract the probability that they dont stand together at all? However,  it's not enough.

Note: $15! $ - Order of all people in line.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "at least" in this problem?

Comment: I think you had the right idea to use the complement. However, your definition of the complement isn't correct. You should look at the probability that no one stands next to a team member.

Comment: this is the problem, ordering them on and off right?

Comment: @ofir attia, is the final answer $\frac{23}{54054}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The people must stand in groups of two, three or five, because otherwise one of them would be alone. That means each team will have exactly one group of five or one group of two and one of three.
First we need to count the number of ways the people can be split up into such groups.

If there are three groups of five, then there are $1\cdot 6=6$ ways. 
(e.g. AAAAABBBBBCCCCC, AAAAACCCCCBBBBB, ...)

If there are two groups of five, there are $3\cdot 2\cdot 6=36$ ways. 
(e.g. AAAAABBCCCCCBBB, AAAAABBBCCCCCBB, ...)

Similarly, if there is one group of five, there are $6\cdot2^2\cdot6=144$ ways. If there are no groups of five, there are $5\cdot2^3\cdot6=240$ ways.
So in total, there are $6+36+144+240=426$ ways.

Now that the groups are fixed assign the people to their places. ($(5!)^3$ ways).

Therefore the probability that each candidate stands next to another candidate from their group is $\frac{426\cdot(5!)^3}{15!}=\frac{71}{126126}\approx 0.000562929...$.